# How to invoke rails.exe in Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed Ruby using RubyInstaller for Windows in C:\Ruby193. I could see C:\Ruby193\bin\rails.exe. I continued to install Rails as explained in https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

When I run `C:\Ruby193\bin\rails.exe --version` in the command prompt, it returns the error message that C:\Ruby193\bin\rails.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Am I using a wrong rails.exe file?

There is a similar discussion at ["rails" command on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513981/rails-command-on-windows) but I could not understand it, being new to Ruby on Rails. What must be my command at the prompt to remove the said double quotes?

Comment: Did you try closing and opening a new terminal?

Comment: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting

Did you make sure your PATH was updated?

Comment: I did not tick the option to add Ruby executables to my PATH. Is there an option to do it now, instead of installing again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `;C:\Ruby193\bin` to your PATH.

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: After updating PATH, do I need to reinstall rails from scratch?

Comment: No, you just need to restart your terminal. Or log off then log on again; I can't remember which :S

Comment: I reinstalled and it went fine. Also sqlite3 needs to be added to the PATH as well.